# How to import groovy files under src

Tags: groovy, visual-studio-code, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to test my Jenkins Shared Library in VS Code.
But don't know how to test my class and vars.
In this image that I attached below, I couldn't figure out naming package, class, file and importing external library running on command line.

[image]

Comment: 1. Package name for AngularParser should correspond to file location. 2. Specify import of package or class in your script. 3. Specify src as a classpath `groovy -cp ./src test.gvy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package names and folder structure are important. 
as @daggett's comment classpath worked

$ groovy -cp ./src test.gvy

https://github.com/cemtopkaya/jenkins-shared-lib

[image]